# Is it possible to build a telegram bot that aggregates posts of multi telegram channel?

Tags: telegram-bot

Requirments:

1- Have a feed of posts that aggregate all posts of multi channels

2- have actions (bot command) on each post

3- When post of channel edited, correspondent post in the telegram bot edited too.
(If it is not possible, I want to know is it possible to edit a message that was sent to multiple recipients in one action or i have to change each of them by message id, chat id)

You can assume you are owner of all these channels and you set your bot as admin of all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Only creator/admins can add bots to channels and only as admins.
2. Bots (for now) can't read messages in channels.
3. Bots (for now) can't view any counters in channels.

So no such bot for now :(